# Errors are occurred about Match - Set in AgensGraph

Tags: cypher, agens-graph

This problem occurs when I use the set clause multiple times in AgensGraph. 
There seems to be a problem with the optimizer. 
Is there a way to bypass it?

```
MATCH (q:QST{ qst_id:1}) <br/>
SET q.prop_solv_time_default = 10<br/>
, q.qst_lvl_default = 13<br/>
, q.key_ku_id = 'C031'<br/>
, q.ku_rate = {'C031':100}<br/>
, q.read_ab_yn = 1<br/>
, q.uds_ab_yn = 1<br/>
, q.app_ab_yn = 1<br/>
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced the same problem you mentioned.

The best way currently you can deal with it is :

```
MATCH (q:QST{ qst_id:1}) 
SET q += {prop_solv_time_default = 10
, q.qst_lvl_default = 13
, q.key_ku_id = 'C031'
, q.ku_rate = {'C031':100}
, q.read_ab_yn = 1
, q.uds_ab_yn = 1
, q.app_ab_yn = 1}
```

The above way changes only the values of properties defined in the set clause.

As far as understand, the optimizer problem occurs at 1.x.x version but 2.x.x.